# I'm having trouble getting my code to work, my goal is to make a loglog graph but I'm unable to get any sort of response from my code

Tags: python

Any thoughts on why this doesn't return me a loglog plot? My goal is to loglog.plot the fractional error between the numerically calculated and analytically driven result over a set of panels. I'm quite sure the simpsonsrule part is fine and I've screwed up afterward around plotting and returning variables.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
%matplotlib inline

def bounds():

    a = 0
    b = 2
    return a,b

def f(x):
        return x**2*numpy.cos(2*x)


def simpsonsRule(n):
    
    n = [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]

    a,b = bounds()
    sum = float()
    sum += f(a) 
    sum += f(b)
    width= (b-a)/(2*n) 
    oddSum = float()
    evenSum = float()
    for i in range(1,n):
        oddSum += f(2*width*i+a)
    sum += oddSum * 2
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
        evenSum += f(width*(-1+2*i)+a)
    sum += evenSum * 4
    return sum * width/3


    


        

    def integrate_analytic(a, b):
        return ((2*b**2-1)*numpy.sin(2*b)+2*b*numpy.cos(2*b))/4 - (((2*a**2-1)*numpy.sin(2*a)+2*a*numpy.cos(2*a))/4)

    def error(n, a, b):

        return (simpsonsRule(n)-integrate_analytic(a, b))/integrate_analytic(a, b)
    
        plt.loglog(error1,error1)

        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))      
        error1 = error(n, a=0, b=2)
        plt.show()
        print(error1)
```

Comment: The code you posted consists of nothing other than function definitions.  You never actually call any of those functions - for example, the one call to `error()` is actually part of the definition of `error()`, so there's no way for it to ever happen.

Comment: also adding to @jasonharper:   not only are the functions not called, but there appear to be nested functions (by the indentation). Did you mean to do this ?